# Analyzing Video quality using Wireshark

Tags: video-streaming, wireshark, http-live-streaming, videoquality

I have an HTTP live stream with a bitrate of 6Mbps in a network and I am streaming the media from the origin server and getting the output at the Mac client after it passes through the real network having the different switches, routers, DSLAM and finally modem to the end client.

Now, at the client I am not getting the good quality of the stream so in order to analyse, i have taken the Wireshark traces. If i see the bps values in the TCP conversation on Wireshark, I don't see any drop in the bitrate. So, is there any way i can see what is causing the loss of quality? There is some issue with any QoS parameter but I am not able to analyse the same.